# Wrapfig package

Tags: multicol, warnings, wrapfig

I have a problem with my code, this it is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum, graphicx, float}

\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{l}{0.2\textwidth}
      \begin{center} 
             \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{hyper.png}
             \vspace{-3mm}
      \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
...
\end{multicols}...
\end{document}
```

I have the following warning:

```
Package wrapfig
Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting enviroment on imput line
```

I think the columns may be generating the problem however I am not sure

Comment: \begin{document} would help.  \centering inside is better than center..  You already get a \intextsep gap above and below.

Comment: Also \usepackage{multicol} is needed. I don't get that error, but I put \lipsum in the multicols. You probably have a list there. (You've also made the image wider than the cutout.)